# How do I read the Black Fang’s melee attacks from the Pathfinder Beginner’s Box?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack, pathfinder-beginner-box

I recently bought the Pathfinder Beginner’s Box and we (all new to RPGs) were discussing the Black Fang’s melee attacks.

Black Fang’s attack is described as follows:

[image: Black Fang]

> **MELEE (standard action)** bite +10 (1d10+3)
> **MELEE (move and standard action)** bite +10 (1d10+3), 2 claws +9 (1d8+2)

I would think that using the second attack that uses both actions, Black Fang could first attack PC with **bite** and then follow with a **2 claws** attack. I learned that with **2 claws** he can target one PC with each claw. So basically, he could either waste one PC with three consecutive attacks, or severly injure up to three PCs. So that would make him *extremely* powerful.

Another thought was that I could attack either with **bite** or with **2 claws**. This would make sense because **2 claws** is already a very powerful attack, but on the other hand this seems stupid because why should I waste the move action and choose **bite** as my attack.

How do I read his *move and standard action* attack, if there are multiple attacks separated by commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black fang can attack with both the bite and the 2 claws in the same turn.

> ## [Natural Attacks](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html):
>
> Attacks made with natural weapons, such as claws and bites, are melee attacks that can be made against any creature within your reach (usually 5 feet). These attacks are made using your full attack bonus and deal an amount of damage that depends on their type (plus your Strength modifier, as normal). You do not receive additional natural attacks for a high base attack bonus. **Instead, you receive additional attack rolls for multiple limb and body parts capable of making the attack** (as noted by the race or ability that grants the attacks). If you possess only one natural attack (such as a bite—two claw attacks do not qualify), you add 1–1/2 times your Strength bonus on damage rolls made with that attack.
>
> ## Multiple Attacks:
>
> A character who **can make** more than one attack per round must use the full-attack action (see Full-Round Actions) in order to get more than one attack.

Comment: I was missing an important piece of information, but I found it when I read the rule on the linked rulebook. I added it to your answer. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: While absolutely accurate for full-on *Pathfinder*, are those rules present in the *Beginner's Box*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan - It seems like the beginner box has substituted "move and standard action" as a simplification of "full round action".

Answer (score 6):

Black Fang can take a standard action to make one bite attack.

Or Black Fang can take *both* its move action *and* its standard action to make one bite attack *and* two claw attacks. Black Fang can make these attacks against one (doomed) creature *or* spread them around against up to three different creatures. When it makes each attack, Black Fang picks against whom that attack will be made.